# Matplotlib Pyplot simple spaghetti plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to write a simple Python3 Matplotlib pyplot only ( no numpy or pandas ) definition to a spaghetti plot 3 lists on one plot with the same axis.
Right now the plots work, but have 3 separate section ranges on the plot?
The data is a simple 10 points time based increment each so I skipped the xaxis list.

```
____ Ain0____ Ain1___ Ain2

0 : 4.9072    1.4307    0.0000     
1 : 4.9072    1.4307    0.0000     
2 : 4.9072    1.4307    0.0000     
3 : 4.9072    1.4307    0.0000     
4 : 4.9072    1.4307    -0.0098     
5 : 4.9072    1.4404    0.0000     
6 : 4.9072    1.4307    0.0049     
7 : 4.9072    1.4307    0.0000     
8 : 4.9072    1.4307    -0.0049     
9 : 4.9072    1.4307    0.0000
```

The y axis limit should be +/- 5.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def Matplot():
    global DIFF_USED,DataSize,Data_Ain0,Data_Ain1,Data_Ain2,Data_Ain3

    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('Volts')
    plt.axis([0, DataSize, -5, 5])
    plt.ylim(top=5)  
    plt.ylim(bottom=-5) 

    plt.plot(Data_Ain0, 'r--', label='Ain0')
    plt.plot(Data_Ain1, 'bs', label='Ain1')
    plt.plot(Data_Ain2, 'g^', label='Ain2')

    plt.show()
```

My plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You're plotting strings. If you want to plot numbers, you need to convert your strings to numbers first.

Comment: Yes, changed data list to float from string and works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should set the user defined axis limits of your plot *after* plotting or else your set values before plotting will be overwritten.

That being said, I am not sure if the following is what you are looking for. I just switched the order of plotting and defining the axis limits. Also, you had two redundant lines of code for setting the y-limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Matplot():
    global DIFF_USED, DataSize, Data_Ain0,Data_Ain1,Data_Ain2,Data_Ain3
    plt.plot(Data_Ain0, 'r--', label='Ain0')
    plt.plot(Data_Ain1, 'bs', label='Ain1')
    plt.plot(Data_Ain2, 'g^', label='Ain2')

    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('Volts')
    plt.axis([0, DataSize, -5, 5]) 
    plt.show()
```

[image]